# Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::create(): Argument #1 ($attributes) must be of type array .. What does this error mean

Tags: php, laravel

Can somebody please tell me what this error means?

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::create(): Argument #1 ($attributes) must be of type array, Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse given, called in D:\1.Schule\Informatik\Dateiarbeit\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\ForwardsCalls.php on line 23
```

This is the Method with the error i think

```
public function store()
    {
        Product::create($this->check())->save();

        return redirect('/');
    }
```

This is the check function i wrote

```
public function check()
    {
        $valid = Validation::all();
        $data = request();
        foreach($valid as $valid){
            if($data->Produkt != $valid->Produkt){
                return redirect()->back()->with('error','Nö, is nich');
            }
            If($data->Produkt == $valid->Produkt){
                $PHmax = $valid[0]->PHmax;
                $PHmin = $valid[0]->PHmin;
                $Wassermax = $valid[0]->Wassermax;
                $Wassermin = $valid[0]->Wassermin;
                $Dichtemax = $valid[0]->Dichtemax;
                $Dichtemin = $valid[0]->Dichtemin;
                return request()->validate([
                    'LieferNr' => ['required', 'min:5', 'max:5'],
                    'Produkt' => 'required',
                    'PH' => ['required', 'numeric', "min:$PHmin", "max:$PHmax"],
                    'Wasser' => "required|numeric|min:$Wassermin|max:$Wassermax",
                    'Dichte' => "required|numeric|min:$Dichtemin|max:$Dichtemax",
                    'Bearbeiter' => 'required',
                ]);
            }
        }
    }
```

I would be glad if you can help me with my error

Comment: You are not passing in any data to the create method. It's first argument is required to be an array of data to be stored, like the error tells you.

Comment: Happens because you return `return redirect()->back()->with('error','Nö, is nich');` instead of an array of validated data.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest rewriting your code to this

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([/*validation rules*/]);
        Product::create($request)->save();

        return redirect('/');
    }
```

The error means you that the result of `check()` is an instance of `Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse` and it needs an array.

If you use the code above, if the validation rules are not met, the code wil terminate with an error. Otherwise it wil use the data of the request to create a new Product